# Laravel 5.6: php artisan migrate --path no esta funcionando

Tags: laravel-5

Quiero usar solamente las migraciones que tengo en la carpeta `database/migrations` dado que tengo otras migraciones provenientes de un paquete que ya no deseo usar. Estoy usando el comando `php artisan migrate --path=/database/migrations`, sin embargo me regresa `Nothing to migrate` a pesar de que en esa direccion esten los archivos de migracion.

Comment: el comando creo que esta incompleto debería ser así `php artisan migrate --path=app/database/migrations/2014_01_17_032743_create_users_table.php`   es decir te falta el nombre de la migracion y su extensión me parece que debe ser así

Comment: y tendrías que hacer una por una

Comment: Encontre por ejemplo que en este tema hacen la migracion de esa forma, pero no tabla por tabla. Solo que lo intento como lo intentan y no funciona:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21641606/laravel-running-migrations-on-app-database-migrations-folder-recursively

Comment: El orden correcto es con la barra invertida. php artisan migrate --path=database\migrations\2014_01_17_032743_create_users_table.php Y para recargar: php artisan migrate:refresh --path...